# Character Limit on Instagram Usernames

Tags: instagram

Does anybody know what the character limit is for Instagram usernames? Google has failed to return any answers to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Limit - 30 symbols. Username must contains only letters, numbers, periods and underscores.

Comment: Tumblr: 32, Facebook: 50, Twitter: 15, Email Standard: 64.

Comment: It would be nice to add a reference link to the answer.

Comment: Looks like the minimum length is 1 character. At least https://www.instagram.com/a/ and https://www.instagram.com/c/ accounts exist.

Comment: Also… Instagram displays usernames in lowercase. Twitter shows mixed case. I personally prefer lowercase; it doesn't make users think when typing in urls directly.

Comment: @luqita - Periods are allowed.  I just experimented with changing my Instagram username and it allowed periods.