# Instagram username Regex -PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have register form and input of "instagram-username".

Instagram  username can included only: `a-z A-Z 0-9 dot(.) underline(_)`

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($instaUsername) && preg_match("/([A-Za-z._])\w+/", $instaUsername)) {
            throw new Exception ("Your name Instagram is incorrect");
}
```

When `$instaUsername = "name.123"` or `"name_123"` this give me the error.

How to make a regular expression according to the following requirements?

`a-z A-Z 0-9 dot(.) underline(_)`

I would love to have good tutorials on regex as comment.

Comment: `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $instaUsername)`, try this?

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari work, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving forward from the comment section, this is what you want:

```
if(!empty($instaUsername) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $instaUsername)) {
            throw new Exception ("Your name Instagram is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, because you cannot start or end with dot (`.`), and it seems like you cannot have consecutive dots either.

Answer (score 24):

Thus you want a regex what validates Instagram usernames? Well then, shall we first do some research on what the requirements actually are? Okay let's start!

...

Well it seems like Instagram doesn't really speak out about the requirements of a valid username. So I made an account and checked what usernames it accepts and what usernames are rejected to get a sense of the requirements. The requirements I found are as following:

- The length must be between 3 and 30 characters.
- The accepted characters are like you said: `a-z A-Z 0-9 dot(.) underline(_)`.
- It's not allowed to have two or more consecutive dots in a row.
- It's not allowed to start or end the username with a dot.

Putting all of that together will result in the following regex:

```
^[\w](?!.*?\.{2})[\w.]{1,28}[\w]$
```

[Try it out here with examples!](https://regex101.com/r/G0echS/)

Comment: One more requirement would be that username's cant contain only numbers.

Comment: @Hansel simply update it to reflect that: `^[a-zA-Z_](?!.*?\.{2})[\w.]{1,28}[\w]$`

Comment: @Pezhvak, your ^ update in your comment does not allow the first character to be a number when it should. Otherwise it's perfect. Can you modify to allow the first character to be a number while still denying entire strings that are only numbers?

Comment: @DevMike well, you're right, it can contain numbers for first character, the original answer is the way to go. to prevent username to contain only numbers i think solution is to use another expression after the first one since i cannot think of a regex to contain both.

Comment: Right, a subsequent expression! makes sense.

Comment: Looks like the minimum length is 1 character. At least [instagram.com/a](https://www.instagram.com/a/) and [instagram.com/c](https://www.instagram.com/c/) accounts exist. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470180/character-limit-on-instagram-usernames#comment57548703_17087528)

Comment: I think accents are not allowed either (á, é, í, ó, ú)

Comment: @Flimtix no mate, First character (1) + Middle characters (28) + Last character (1) = 30 characters maximum.

Comment: @MimoudiX Yes, that is the maximum... but the **minimum** is 1.

Comment: @Flimtix the minimum is 3, try it https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 15):

[jstassen](http://blog.jstassen.com/2016/03/code-regex-for-instagram-username-and-hashtags/) has a good write up on insta user names:

```
(?:^|[^\w])(?:@)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)
```

Comment: For username only, `^([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)$` works for me.

Comment: That looks way to complex, for something as simple as @UnderPhp is asking for.

Answer (score 3):

I found a lot of the answers here way too complicated and didn't account for a username being used in a sentence (like `hey @man... what's up?`),  so I did my own

```
/@(?:[\w][\.]{0,1})*[\w]/
```

This says:

1. `@`: Find an @ symbol (optional)
2. `([\w][\.]{0,1})+`: Find a word character (A-Z, 0-9, _) and up to 1 dot in a row, `*` as many times as you like (e.g. allow `@u.s.e.r.n.a.m.e`, but not `@u..sername`)
3. `(?:` this before the above just means "don't actually create a capturing group for this"
4. `[\w]` end with a word character (i.e. don't allow a final dot, like `@username.` should exclude the dot)

If you want to limit the username to 30chars like IG does, then:

```
@(?:(?:[\w][\.]{0,1})*[\w]){1,29}
```

This just wraps everything in another non-capturing `(?:` group and limits the total length to 29 chars

Comment: Only numbers is not allowed either

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
~^([a-z0-9._])+$~i
```

You can use [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) to match the start (`^`) and the end `$` of your input. And use the [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i` for case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my edit was rejected because i should have posted it as an answer or comment so

```
if(!empty($instaUsername) && !preg_match("/([A-Za-z._])\w+/", $instaUsername)) {
        throw new Exception ("Your name Instagram is incorrect");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this pattern

```
if(empty($instaUsername) or preg_match("/[a-z|A-Z|0-9|\.|\_]+$/", $instaUsername)==false) {
            throw new Exception ("Your name Instagram is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping dot `.` and underscore `_`? Why do you include pipe `|` in the character class? Why do you add `i` and `m` flags?

Comment: @Toto pipe mean or in regex and `i` mean caseinsensitive in string and `m` mean multi line 
It may have been used to scape these characters `_` ,dot sign

Comment: You're wrong. I suggest you to read a [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) before answering. Pipe in a character class means pipe, the `i` flag is useless here because you have `a-z` & `A-Z` OP doesn't talk about multiline. Moreover your code throws an exception for valid username.

Answer (score 0):

Reg
Useful [regex](https://regexr.com/3cg7r)

```
(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

try This regex should work for you:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:[._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/u
```